# No network after installing Ubuntu on Hyper-V

Tags: ubuntu, hyper-v

I followed the below links for installing Ubuntu Server 11.04 as a virtual machine on Hyper-V. However, after installation, Ubuntu can't access the LAN. Please help. Thanks.

http://www.panterlo.com/2010/10/10/ubuntu-10-10-and-hyper-v-r2/
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/virtual_pc_guy/archive/2010/10/21/installing-ubuntu-server-10-10-on-hyper-v.aspx

Answer (score 2):

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc794868(WS.10).aspx

Since Ubuntu is not officially supported by Hyper-V, you can only hack and see if you are fortunate.

You can leave a comment under http://blogs.msdn.com/b/virtual_pc_guy/archive/2010/10/21/installing-ubuntu-server-10-10-on-hyper-v.aspx to see if this Microsoft employee can shed some light.

> Dan Visan  Dan Visan
>   IT Owner&Student
>   0 Recent Achievements 3 0 0 New Wiki Commentator New Blog Rater New Blog Commentator View Profile 9 Jun 2011 2:19 PM Just installed Ubuntu Server 11.04. Works great. Thanks!

At least one user reported that he/she has Ubuntu 11.04 working fine.

Answer (score 1):

See here: http://narendrapatel.com/2011/05/installing-ubuntu-serve-11-04-64bit-on-hyper-v/

You can see that it is the 11.04 version, on the Hyper-V, with Networking working.
Just follow the steps there.

I think that though it isn't fully supported, you can still work with network since other Linux distros do support it, and they are the same in the base (Networking and so on).